# Составляют ли длины вводимых строк возрастающую арифметическую прогрессию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вводятся 3 строки в случайном порядке. Напишите программу, которая выясняет можно ли из длин этих строк построить возрастающую арифметическую прогрессию.

Формат входных данных:
На вход программе подаются три строки, каждая на отдельной строке.

Формат выходных данных:
Программа должна вывести строку «YES», если из длин введенных слов можно построить арифметическую прогрессию, «NO» в ином случае.

```
Sample Input 1:

abc
a
abcde
```

```
Sample Output 1:

YES
```

МОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
from math import *
a = len(input())
b = len(input())
c = len(input())
if (2 * b - c - a) * (2 * c - b - a) * (2 * a - b - c):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: from math import *
a = len(input())
b = len(input())
c = len(input())
if (2 * b - c - a) * (2 * c - b - a) * (2 * a - b - c):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')

Comment: Дайте нормальный заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

действительно должно соблюдаться одно из следующих условий:

```
2b = c + a
2c = a + b
2a = b + c
```

поэтому одно из выражений

```
2b - c - a
2c - a - b
2a - b - c
```

должно равняться 0, а значит

```
if (2 * b - c - a) * (2 * c - b - a) * (2 * a - b - c):
    print('NO')
else:
    print('YES')
```

а не наоборот

Comment: Вообще, условие лучше переписать через логические операции: `(2*b == c - a) or (2*c == b - a) or (2*a == b - c)`

Comment: @insolor, да это более понятно было бы, но если таких операций миллиард и это не питон, а c++, к примеру, то для улучшения производительности лучше уйти от условий :)

Comment: @Zhihar, да, но это Python, а не С/С++, и даже в C/C++ это скорее всего будет преждевременной оптимизацией.

Comment: @insolor, не спорю. Кстати все таки интересно - для python условия как-то влияют на производительность или по сравнению с тем, что там с переменными происходит условия уже совершенно не критичны?

Comment: @Zhihar Я потестил, условия работают чуть быстрее. А если выполняется первое равенство, так вообще в 2 раза быстрее, потому что с логикой точно после выполнения условия то, что после `or` уже не выполняется - это стандартная оптимизация. А вот для умножения вряд ли такая оптимизация делается, скорее всего при математике выполняются все действия, которые есть, оптимизация не производится. Так что отказ от логики в пользу математики - это не оптимизация, а наоборот - запутывание кода и отказ от встроенной оптимизации.